# Stop javascript on component unmount (Svelte)

Tags: svelte

If I have a component that initiates a database query (async), and the user changes their mind and hits a key that destroys the component, the javascript from that component is still active, and when the query returns still processes it as if the component still existed, which it does not. If that processing is expensive (like drawing a complex graph with thousands of datapoints), this can degrade the user experience, who believes they've aborted whatever they were doing and will never see the effects of that work.

So, is there a preferred way to deal with this? I supposed I could set an onDestroy() event handler to set a local variable and have my code check that variable to see whether or not the component still exists before proceeding with processing query-returned data. Is there something more streamlined? Some $$ object I can check to interrogate self-component status and see that it no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the current component state, setting a flag manually is the closest thing.

If you use markup directives you can prevent accidentally running additional work. The DOM is only updated while the component is mounted, so if you have something like this:

```html
{#await queryDB() then data}
  <Graph {data} />
{/await}
```

No further processing will happen after the query, if the component has been unmounted in-between.